# SQL: Deleting Duplicates using Not in and Group by

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates, notin

I have the following SQL Syntax to delete duplicate rows, but never are any rows affected.

```
DELETE FROM content_stacks WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT id 
FROM content_stacks
GROUP BY user_id, content_id
);
```

The subquery itself is returning the id list of first entries correctly.

```
SELECT id 
FROM content_stacks
GROUP BY user_id, content_id
```

When I'm inserting the results list as a string it is working, too:

```
DELETE FROM content_stacks WHERE id NOT IN (239,231,217,218,219,232,233,220,230,226,234,235,224,225,221,223,222,227,228,229,236,237,238,216,208,209,210,204,211,212,242,203,240,201,241,205,206,207,213,214,215);
```

I checked many similar examples and this should be working in my opinion. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from Meyssam Toluie is not working as it is but I made a similar solution with the same idea with rownumbers:

```
DELETE FROM content_stacks WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, content_id)row_num
      FROM content_stacks
    ) sub
WHERE row_num > 1)
```

This is working for me now.

My first command did not work because: The group by command does not show all ids in the output, but they are still there, so in fact all ids were returned in the NOT IN id-list. The row number seems to be the easiest way for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First find first rows using `ROW_NUMBER` Then delete record with row number greater than 1:

```
WITH CTE  AS (
SELECT id , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, content_id, ORDER BY id) rn 
FROM content_stacks
)
DELETE cs 
FROM content_stacks cs
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.id = cs.id
WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Am sorry to ask but if your deleting why would u need to group the records.
Are not just increasing the runtime.

Comment: to just return the id of the first entry of two duplicate items.